# Wrong files size after combining files

Tags: linux, terminal, cat, xargs

I have a folder containing many `.txt` files with a total size of 7.2GB.

After I combine them all into a single `all.txt` file, it's size is only 4.8GB, why?

I tested multiple methods, all resulting in a 4.8GB file.

The methods I used:

```
xargs < list.txt perl -pe 1 > all.txt

xargs < list.txt cat > all.txt
```

Why is my combined file size smaller than the size of the original files?
Is there a way to combine all `.txt` files without loosing it's size?

Comment: What is some sample contents of `list.txt`? You do know what the [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) command does?

Comment: sample of `list.txt` are the name of my files 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt ... I used `xargs` because cat or perl cant handle large number of files.

Comment: I need a command that can combine all my `.txt` files into a single `.txt` file.

Comment: Can you test with a simple loop that iterates over all files and appends to the resulting file? Like e.g. `for file in $(cat list.txt); do cat $file >> all.txt; done` Does it work? And how do you check the file sizes? How do you get the size 7.2GB?

Comment: You were right! The problem was that I am getting the wrong size using the `du` command. So I tested `du -shc --apparent-size` and got the right size 4.5GB. It's a weird thing, `du` vs `du --apparent size`. Thanks

Comment: Some programmer dude, please add the answer, so I can upvote and star. thanks man

Comment: I was just guessing and speculating without any idea what so ever about the reason. I really think you deserve the credit for finding out yourself, so go ahead and add an answer yourself! :)